# CSS files in HTML fragments won't load under android in Cordova / Visual Studio app

Tags: android, cordova, winjs, visual-studio-cordova

I'm getting really weird behavior when I try to load HTML fragments within a single-page Cordova app in Visual Studio.

I'm using WinJS to create a PageControlNavigator that loads other HTML files into a main page.  This works just fine in Windows apps.  In Android apps, the html content will load, but the system can never find the css files I define.

My file structure follows the standard template from a Visual Studio Cordova typescript template (i.e. www folder contains index.html and several folders with css files and scripts).  I have an additional folder in the www root folder called Views with subfolders for each of the views, i.e. Main, Accounts, About, etc.  Each of these subfolders contains the HTML file I'm loading as a fragment and the css file that goes with them.

Let's use the MainView.html file as an example in the Main subfolder of the View folder (all under the www root folder).  If I define the css file like this:

```
<link href="MainView.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then the VS debugger tells me it can't find the file and it thinks the file is located at:

```
file:///android_asset/www/MainView.css
```

Ok, that's fine.  Maybe I need to put the full path from root.  Now, if I change the link to this:

```
<link href="Views/Main/MainView.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It still doesn't work and VS tells me it was looking for the file here:

```
file:///android_asset/www/Views/Main/Views/Main/MainView.css
```

Notice the doubling of the path!  **What is happening here?**

Finally, I've tried what works in Windows apps for my fragments:

```
<link href="/www/Views/Main/MainView.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now the debugger thinks I was looking here:

```
file:///www/Views/Main/MainView.css
```

I'm fine with a different approach for Android than for Windows. That's what the merges folder is for.  However, I can't get it to work using fragments in Android.  What has finally worked is to define **all** of my css files in the main index.html file.  I don't really want that because I'd like to be able to redefine classes without having to tie them to page ids.

Can anyone suggest a better method?